# Unable to pass JSON for custom application configuration in EMR creation via Service Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr, aws-service-catalog

I am unable to pass the JSON having the custom application configurations from the Service Catalog for creation of EMRs and getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: Invalid config property. Property key, value may not be null and total length may not exceed 1024
```

The length of the property value I am passing is more than 1024 characters. Is that what is causing this problem? What is the work-around for this?

Comment: Same here. I want to add some additional libraries, but that makes my `spark.*.extraClassPath` longer than 1024.